# Weighted percentage questions (Logic \ Design)

Tags: logic

Im trying to work out the progress of answering 3 questions.
The questions indicate the state of a project's completion

I have a form with 3 questions, scored 50%, 40% and 10% Max respectively for the answers which combined add up to 100%.

Each question has 3 answers, a full or partial score and a full score respectively; "Yes", "No" and "NA".
If the person answers "NA" for any of the questions I was giving it full score.

However this skews the percentage progress as just putting "NA" on the first answer already calculates a percentage of 50% which is not realistic, as percentage should be based on the work done, not avoided.

The total should be 0%, until the next questions is answered "Yes" which adds 40$, the third question will add another 10% for a "Yes" answer.

This combined is 50%, and to achieve 100% i could have the first answer of "NA" combined the 2 other answers and multiply by 2 which would equal 100%. This would work out nicely.

If the 40% was answered as "NA" replacing a score of 40% means 1.6666666667 is the multiplier to achieve a 100% again.

But what if two questions were answered NA?